# Activity and fragments coding best practices

Tags: android

Where can I find some best practices guide or tutorial regarding fragments and activities to prevent a messy code or confusion with their lifecycle?

Comment: Hi, have you cheked the official android documentation about that, it's pretty simple and very clear [android doc](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) also [vogella tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidFragments/article.html) really helped me when i began using fragments

Answer (score 0):

Everything you need is right here http://developer.android.com/training/index.html

Answer (score 0):

I would check out the [official documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) for fragments and activities.